# can I enable and disable fitbounds() on leaflet?

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

i am using

```
map.fitBounds(arrayofcoordinates)
```

I am drawing multiple polylines to show path for each users moving on map, using fitBounds() complete path is not visible. I want to remove fitBounds() if I click on a marker to see its path. and after that enable fitBounds() to see all markers moving on map. I do not know if it is possible or not. Please help.

If yes then how ?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific: fitBounds is a function you call. You can not call it if you don't want to. What do you mean by enable and disable?

Comment: I am drawing multiple polylines to show path for each users moving on map, using fitBounds() complete path is not visible. I want to remove fitBounds() if I click on a marker to see its path. and after that enable fitBounds() to see all markers moving on map. I do not know if it is possible or not. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable as a flag which will have value 0 or 1 . Write fitBounds() inside if statement like

```
var boundFlag = 0;
if(boundFlag = 1)
  {
    map.fitBounds(arrayofcoordinates) 
  }
```

To change the value of variable "boundFlag" 0 or 1 you can use custom button on leaflet.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icontrol